# Use multiple criteria on Reports

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have the following code which does not work:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptHome", acViewPreview, , "Room LIKE '*" & Room.Value & "*'" And "Flat LIKE '*" & Flat.Value & "*'"
```

I expect the report to include the records with `Room` and `Flat` only.

However, the code works fine when used like below:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptHome", acViewPreview, , "Room LIKE '*" & Room.Value 
& "*'"
```

Is it possible to add another criteria as in my first attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the keyword '**AND**' must but included in the condition

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptHome", acViewPreview, , "Room LIKE '*" & Room.Value & "*' AND Flat LIKE '*" & Flat.Value & "*'`
```